# Personalized mails to multiple people using JavaMailSender

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I would like to send mails to multiple people using javamailsender, with personalized salutations.

> To : Abc,xyz
>
> Mail Content:
>
> Hi Abc, ...

I am able to send mails to multiple people but unable to find a way to replace placeholders that could be used for recipient's name.

Comment: Your question is way to broad. Please refactor it according to the how-toask-guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @tgr!
The question is as simple as I could make it sound, in short I just need placeholders that could be replaced on client side

Comment: Please provide any findings you got from your own research and show the code, you want to make work. Your question allows for a variety of answers from telling you to use regex to go for springframework. Please be as specific as possible, to allow for specific answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is having some contradiction. As per your question, let's imagine different people would receive an email with the "To:" list showing multiple receivers, e.g. To: Abc, xyz. However, each of them is having the email contents showing their own name ...

The result would be as shown in below graph:

[image]

I think it would be something which could only be achieved on client side (receiver side), but not possible through the API on server side (sender side).

If you really want to have some control on sender side, then you have no other options but could only send the email several times depending on how many recipients you want.

Below is an example for a reference:

```
private JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage() {

    String[] multipleRecepients = new String[] {"ABC", "xyz"};
    String subject = " This is Email subject";

    String text = "Hi {0} ,\r\n Nice to reach you through email.";
    MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(text);


    for (int i = 0 ; i < multipleRecepients.length; i++) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(multipleRecepients[i]);
        message.setSubject(subject); 
        message.setText(mf.format(new Object[] {multipleRecepients[i]}));
        emailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

**Remark:**

For the above example code, don't try to put the multipleRecepients array into setTo(...)  [i.e. message.setTo(multipleRecepients) ]method directly. Otherwise, each recipient will receive a copy which doesn't belong to him/her (The salutation is another receiver's name).

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer, but I want all my recipients to know who all got the mail, so sending multiple mails is not an option.
And it does look impossible to be handled through server side, but I was wondering if there was something that I was not able to dig into.

Comment: For the captioned scenario, as each receiver would receive the same copy of email content (just the salutation is different) as described. In business world, it would usually simply use "Hi all", "Dear valued XXX", etc. to resolve the problem. Because the solution as described in the graph above, I think is technically infeasible if only want to make changes on sender side.

Comment: Sending a different message to each recipient and then trying to make it look like all recipients got that same message seems like a bad idea.  You can do it by setting the To field in the message to all recipients and then using the send method that allows you to specify the recipients and only specifying one recipient for each different copy of the message you send.  But again, I don't recommend it.

Comment: @garykwwong that would definitely work with salutation, but I had a different use case. Thanks for the help!